# Creating a trigger to update total count when any new employee is inserted

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create trigger in which update total count when any new employee inserted in pgadmin 4

here is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE counter SET counter.count = counter.count + 1
```

Comment: In Postgres you need to write a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) that is then used when you [create the trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). See the examples [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: didn't get you @GordonLinoff

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have tried i am having below error
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 5: AS $BODY$CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger

Comment: `AS $BODY$CREATE TRIGGER ...`  makes no sense. Did you even bother to read the [examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the manual?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, In pgadmin 4, when we write any trigger, sql automatically writes our code in some format and in that it gives that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the update in the Trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_counter()
  RETURNS trigger
AS $$
        BEGIN
            UPDATE counter SET count = count + 1; --where clause?
                 RETURN NULL;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The Trigger should call that function.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON employee
    FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE procedure update_counter();
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1cb79e10390b3d74a04876b854916690)

Comment: it gives sysntax error as below

ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 5: AS $BODY$CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_counter()

Comment: @Samir : It works, check the DEMO link in my answer,

Comment: Yes I have checked how can i implement it on pgadmin 4?

Comment: @Samir: what exactly is your question? Just run those two SQL statements

Comment: @Samir : I'm not familiar with PgAdmin, but I don't see why it should make any difference. The code is syntactically correct and must work in any Postgres db / tool

Comment: yes, it is correct just i have add "RETURN null" before END; because in trigger you need to return something. because in my case i am calling it from java api that's why it's compulsary to return something.

Thanks @KaushikNayak